How to use method from converter by default
I have a mapper
@Mapper(uses = {PostConverter.class, TagConverter.class})
public interface TagMapper {

    void update(TagRequestDTO source, @MappingTarget Tag destination);

    Tag dtoToTag(TagRequestDTO dto);

    TagResponseDTO tagToDTO(Tag tag);
    
    Tag longToTag(Long id);
}

Is there a way to set the behavior of MapStruct so that it uses a method from TagConverter, rather than generating its own? (Using default methods and abstract classes is not possible.)
Converter
public interface TagConverter {
    
    Tag longToTag(Long id);

    Set<Long> fromTagsToLong(Set<Tag> tags);

    Set<Tag> fromLongsToTags(Set<Long> ids);
}

Implementation
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TagConverterImpl implements TagConverter {

    private final TagRepository repository;

    @Override
    public Tag longToTag(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new EntityNotFoundException("Tag", id));
    }
}

I read the MapStruct docs, but I didn't find a solution.

Doesn't it generate its own method because you defined the longToTag method in the interface even though it's already in TagConverter?

So the thing is that it generates its own, and I need a method from TagConverter, and sometimes I have to take TagConverter instead of TagMapper in the code to convert Long to Tag

Why do you need a Mapper's method to convert Long to Tag? You already have the TagConverter to do the job. It smells to  over-engineering

Assuming that you are using Spring IoC, I believe you can customize the mapping using a decorator.
To apply a decorator to a mapper class, specify it using the @DecoratedWith annotation:
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
@DecoratedWith(TagMapperDecorator.class)
public interface TagMapper {

    Tag longToTag(Long id);
}


When using @DecoratedWith on a mapper with component model spring, the generated implementation of the original mapper is annotated with the Spring annotation @Qualifier("delegate"). To autowire that bean in your decorator, add that qualifier annotation as well.

The TagMapperDecorator shown below customizes the longToTag(Long id). It uses the TagConverter to convert the Long value to Tag object.
public abstract class TagMapperDecorator implements TagMapper {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("delegate")
    private TagMapper delegate;

    @Autowired
    private TagConverter tagConverter;

    @Override
    public Tag longToTag(Long id) {
        return tagConverter.longToTag(id);
    }
}


The generated class that extends the decorator is annotated with Spring’s @Primary annotation. To autowire the decorated mapper in the application, nothing special needs to be done:

@Autowired
private TagMapper tagMapper; // injects the decorator, with the injected original mapper


If you want to use the method from TagConverter then you should not define your own method in the TagMapper. Your mapper should look like:
@Mapper(uses = {PostConverter.class, TagConverter.class})
public interface TagMapper {

    void update(TagRequestDTO source, @MappingTarget Tag destination);

    Tag dtoToTag(TagRequestDTO dto);

    TagResponseDTO tagToDTO(Tag tag);
    
}

